# Ring of integer of quadratic fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I do not make sense of the following argument. We want to determine the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. An element $\alpha = a + b \sqrt{d}$ is an algebraic integer iff its minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$  has coefficients in $\mathbb  Z$. Expanding the minimal polynomial, this translates into the two conditions

$$2a \in \mathbb Z \quad \text{and} \quad a^2 - b^2 d \in \mathbb Z.$$

How do we get the usual conditions depending on $q \equiv 1$ mod $4$ or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{m})$ for $m$ a squarefree integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411949/algebraic-integers-of-mathbbq-sqrtm-for-m-a-squarefree-integer)

Comment: @DanielMroz Yes, thanks